How to execute SQL statements against on premise Oracle DB in AWS Glue
I am trying to update a table in my Oracle DB using AWS Glue. I know that PySpark is not really meant for updating tables or inserting. More for reading. Though, I am trying to update all rows for a column in a original table to show a status as verified (essentially that all the records have been loaded into an s3).
I have tried using this post to help me
How to run arbitrary / DDL SQL statements or stored procedures using AWS Glue
But I keep getting
Error Category: UNCLASSIFIED_ERROR; An error occurred while calling z:java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection. IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection (CONNECTION_ID=...)
I am using a oracle:jdbc:thin url, and for some reason when I try ro connect to to my database, it does not connect and I get that error. My AWS Glue connection does indeed work though.
I have thought of using cx Oracle, and I do not want to have to install it onto my environment, but I am trying to find all alternatives.

cx_Oracle was renamed to python-oracledb a couple of years ago.  It no longer needs Oracle Instant Client so installation is trivial.  Give it a go.  https://pypi.org/project/oracledb/
